# MinGW+cmake on Windows 10 produce error: '__MINGW_EXTENSION' does not name a type

Tags: cmake, mingw

I have spent long time developing C/C++ under Linux, now I'm trying to port/compile my [project](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/tree/master/cpp) under windows where I have no experinece. I want to keep the workflow as close to Linux as possible so I go with `g++/MinGW` and `cmake`.

When I do standard approach

```
cd Build
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
make
```

I got tons of following errors:

```
PS D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build> make VERBOSE=1
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SD:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp -BD:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build\CMakeFiles D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/MinGW/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/Build'
C:/MinGW/bin/make  -f common\algorithms\CMakeFiles\algorithms.dir\build.make common/algorithms/CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/Build'
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\common\algorithms D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build\common\algorithms D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build\common\algorithms\CMakeFiles\algorithms.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/Build'
C:/MinGW/bin/make  -f common\algorithms\CMakeFiles\algorithms.dir\build.make common/algorithms/CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/Build'
[  1%] Building CXX object common/algorithms/CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/main.cpp.obj
cd /d D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\Build\common\algorithms && C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe  @CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -Wall -std=c++17 -g -Og -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing  -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-write-strings -Wno-format -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-but-set-variable  -Wno-narrowing -Wno-unused-result  -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-comment -Wno-misleading-indentation  -Werror=return-type -o CMakeFiles\algorithms.dir\main.cpp.obj -c D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\common\algorithms\main.cpp
In file included from c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdlib.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\c++\6.1.0\cstdlib:75,
                 from D:/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/common/utils/testUtils.h:6,  
                 from D:\git\SimpleSimulationEngine\cpp\common\algorithms\main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\crtdefs.h:35:1: error: '__MINGW_EXTENSION' does not name a type
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\crtdefs.h:45:1: error: '__MINGW_EXTENSION' does not name a type
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\crtdefs.h:52:9: error: 'size_t' does not name a type
 typedef size_t rsize_t;
         ^~~~~~
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\crtdefs.h:62:1: error: '__MINGW_EXTENSION' does not name a type
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 intptr_t;
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\crtdefs.h:75:1: error: '__MINGW_EXTENSION' does not name a type
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 uintptr_t;
```

I'm not sure my MinGW environment and libraries are setup properly, since I tried some older minGW version before, than I reinstalled it. Also I have installed [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) in an atempt to install GLEW. But I do not use MSYS2 now, I use some stand alone instalation of MinGW and cmake.

There is nothing special in my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8 )
project ( SimpleSimulationEngine )
set(default_build_type Release)
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++17" )

SET( IGNORE_WARRNING_FLAGS "-Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-write-strings -Wno-format -Wno-parentheses -Wno-unused-but-set-variable  -Wno-narrowing -Wno-unused-result  -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-comment -Wno-misleading-indentation " )
SET( WARRNING_TO_ERROR "-Werror=return-type")
SET( AXULIARY_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -Og -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing ")
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${AXULIARY_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${IGNORE_WARRNING_FLAGS} 
message ( "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} )
```

When I check my environment variables/path there does not seem to be anything fishy (like two versions of MinGW)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show the full gcc command displayed with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: @ssbssa : I updated my answer with `make VERBOSE=1`, thanks for suggestion. I personally don't see anything suspicious in the verbose output. Hopefully, you can see more.

Comment: I just tried this command with my x86_64-w64-mingw32 gcc-6.1, and I don't get these errors. I had to add some include directories `-Icpp\common\utils -Icpp\common\math`, which I assume are in your case in `CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/includes_CXX.rsp`, and add the define `-D_USE_MATH_DEFINES`.
So your contents of CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/includes_CXX.rsp may be interesting as well.

Comment: So you are able to compile the code on windows?

Comment: Oh, I don't have there `CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/`, see screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/h?preview=Screenshot+2020-10-27+11.59.24.png